# angular2 file download in java

Tags: java, file, angular, blob

How could download a file using Angular2 and Java?

There is a GET HTTP call which returns the file data:

> If receive a byte[] array, the file (in this case ODT, but could be
>   other format) opens as a document with the literal byte content
>   written in it: "UEsDBBQAAAgAAPBZjklexjIMJwAAACcAAAA"
>
> If receive a blob object , it shows
>   "{"binaryStream":{},"wrappedBlob":{"binaryStream":{}}}" in the
>   document

**Angular2 code:**

```
goFile() {
   //This service calls @angular/http for a GET request and returs the response
   //ends up doing:
   //   this.http.get(url, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
   //       .map(res => res.blob())

   this.myService.subscribe(result=> { this.saveFile(result); });
   return false;
}


downloadFile(file: any) {
   var blob = new Blob([file], {type: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'});
   var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(url);
}
```

**Java** code just reads the file and returns a blob or byte array (in each case tried):

```
   byte[] file = FileUtils.getFile("E:/file.odt");
   return file;

   byte[] file = FileUtils.getFile("E:/file.odt");
   Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(fichero);
   return blob;
```

**UPDATE**

I believe the problem comes that data is being received as a json object, something setup in the system i am working.

Have tried intead to return byte[] from java and try  to convert to a blob in Angular2 (for a txt file):

```
   //file is returned by a call to http.get which has a map:
   //     .map(res => res.text())
   var blob = new Blob([file], {type: 'text/plain'});

   var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(objectUrl);
```

but returns a page with the byte content ("YWJj"), obviously the content received is not converted to a proper blob object.

Also tried with same result:

```
   var byteArray = new Uint8Array(file);
   var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

there is not solution for different mime types without using additional plugins?

Comment: Using [Transfer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/)

Comment: Have you tried using `.subscribe(res =>{...})` instead of `map`?

Comment: Maybe you have to set the `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob`, in the options parameter of the http-request

Comment: thanks for the help. tried different solutions, updated the question.

Comment: If you consider using 3rd party libs, try FileSaver.js: `import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
...
let file = new Blob(['hello world'], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
saveAs(file, 'helloworld.csv');`